# Atom in first order programming

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, integer-programming

Consider the following statements regarding **atom** in first order programming

> An atom is a *predicate applied to a tuple of objects*.
>
> **Atoms**:  An atom evaluates to a number.
>
> 1. A scalar, a real-valued constant
> 2. A predicate *applied to 0 or more terms*: $pred(t_1,...,t_n)$. Each predicate is annotated with its range, a bounded interval of
>      $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Confused with the above definition. Does atom can be a predicate with partial number of elements in its inputs assigned to objects? I mean does an atom is a variable free predicate or not?

**Example**:

`Is_son_of(Rama,Dasharatha, Rama)` is an atom for sure.

But `Is_son_of(Ravana, Bhoomi, x)` is an atom or not where x is a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *atom* is an [atomic sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_sentence) i.e. a sentence that is not "decomposable" in further sentences.

This means that is a sentence where no connectives occur.

In the syntax of [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formation_rules), an *atomic formula* is a *predicate* symbol $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with $n$ "argument places" (place holders to be filled with "inputs") with $n$ *terms* (i.e. "names") of the language.

According to the syntax specifications of the language, *variables* : $x,y,\ldots$ are terms.

A *sentence* is a formula without *free* occurrences of variables.

Thus, $\text {Is_son_of}(\text{Tom},x)$ is a correct (well-formed) formula but it is not a *sentence*, because in it we have an occurrence of the free variable $x$.

$\text {Is_son_of}(\text{Tom},\text{Bill})$ instead, is a *sentence*, and thus an *atomic* one.