# What are not examples of Atomic Formulas?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am having trouble understanding what exactly an atomic formula is and its relevance.

The definition I have is as follows: An **Atomic Formula** is an expression of the form $A(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ where $A$ is an n-ary predicate symbol and each $t_i$ is a term (i.e., variable or constant symbol).

I believe my confusion primarily lies in the fact that it seems to just be a predicate with values filled in rather than a "standard" formula (using $\neg, \lor, \land, \rightarrow, \leftarrow$). Moreover, I am having issue understanding when this would not be the case. I.e., what is an example of a non-atomic formula?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098223/atom-in-first-order-programming)

Comment: $R(x)$ is an *atomic* formula while $\lnot R(x)$ is not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah, I see. So since formulas are built on predicates, an expression such as $R(x)$ is an atomic formula and introducing any other connectives (or other predicates) such as $\neg R(x)$ would make it a non-atomic formula?

Comment: Exactly........

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to MSE!

Recall how formulas are (recursively) defined. let's work with the [language of arithmetic](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Language_of_Arithmetic) for concreteness. So we have symbols $0,1,S,+,\times,<,=$ with their expected arities.

First we make the *terms*, which pick out elements of our structure. For instance

- $0$
- $S(0)$
- $(1 + 1) + 1$
- $1 \times y$
- $y \times (y + 1)$
- etc.

Next we define the *atomic* formulas. These are "atoms" in the sense that they "can't be broken down". These have truth values, but are the most basic questions we can ask. For us,

- $0 = S(0)$
- $(1 + 1) + 1 < 1 \times y$
- etc.

Notice these all look like one of the relation symbols given in our language, with terms inside it. Notice, importantly, that these have nothing to do with the *truth* values of the formulas. It only has to do with whether it's a question we can *ask*. Of course, there's plenty of *nonatomic* formulas too:

- $\big ( 0 = S(0) \big ) \land \big ( (1+1) + 1 < 1 \times y \big )$
- $\lnot (0 = S(0))$
- $\big ( (0 = x) \to (x \times y = 0) \big )$
- etc.

Notice these are all formulas, which have truth values (at least once we instantiate the variables). They *aren't* "atomic" though, in the sense that they *can* be broken down into smaller parts.

If you like, formulas are trees, with leaves corresponding to atomic formulas and internal nodes corresponding to the connectives. See the example below

[image: an example of the tree structure]

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Hmm, I thought expressions such as $(1 + 1) + 1$ don't count as terms unless you are considering that a symbol for a constant (which doesn't seem correct).

Comment: Do you mean if I'm considering $1$ as a symbol for a constant? Or if I'm considering $(1+1)+1$ as a symbol for a constant?

Comment: Considering $(1 + 1) + 1$ as a constant. If not, that will not be a term?

Comment: $(1+1)+1$ is a term even if it is not a constant. You should think of a term as "something that names an element of the structure". So $x$ names an element (albeit one whose value we don't know), $0$ names an element, $1$ names an element. Similarly, $1+1$ names an element, and in general if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms (that is, they name elements) then $t_1 + t_2$ is again a term (it names another element). I don't know what book you're reading, but you can find this (say) on page 11 of Hodges _A Shorter Model Theory_

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain their issue with this answer?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, In your example of atomic formula you mentioned that $S(0)=0$ right? But $S(0)=1$??

Comment: @Rahul -- a formula is just an allowable question to ask. The answer might be true or false depending on the model. In the standard model of the language of arithmetic (namely $\mathbb{N}$), this particular formula is false. However, it's still an atomic formula.